# Google Datastore Composite Index with __key__ desc not working when queried

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have an index created like this:

```
ancestor: NONE
indexId: CICAgJiUpoMK
kind: Candidate
projectId: financialplanning-270210
properties:
- direction: ASCENDING
  name: activity.lastupdatets
- direction: DESCENDING
  name: id
state: READY
```

but when running the following query:

```
select activity.lastupdatets from candidate order by activity.lastupdatets asc, __key__ desc
```

It fails with an error like `"...no suitable composite index found..."`

Comment: key is actually __key__ so nothing incorrect there.. just fyi

Comment: key was actually prefixed and suffixed with two underscores, so no problem with that.. just fyi

Comment: What does that `__key__` represents in your query? The only fields present in your index are `activity.lastupdatets` and `id`, shouldn't you be using `id` instead of `__key__`?